# parquet in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, hortonworks-sandbox

I am learning how to use Hive with the Hortonwork Sandbox, however whenever I am not able to. When I create a table, the data is not shown, so I decided to add this query:

```
Create external table tripinfo (
  VendorID string,
  pickup string,
  dropoff string,
  Passenger string,
  distance string,
  Pickloc string,
  droploc string,
  rate string,
  store string,
  payment string,
  amount string,
  extra string,
  tax string,
  improvement string,
  tip string,
  tolls string,
  tap string)
row format serde "parquet.hive.serde.PaquetHiveSerDe"
stored as 
INPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat"
OUTPUTFORMAT "parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat"
Location "/user/taxi/yellow data/trip/";
```

however, it shows this error: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Cannot find class 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat'`

the parquet file is already in HDFS, separated by " " and is huge (as you might have expected)
Am I doing something wrong, or is ther any way to create a table with parquet data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are reading this page? - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Parquet

Notice the header **Hive 0.10-0.12**. The sandbox should at least be using Hive 1.x, maybe even 2.x, so you should just use a query like so

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE name (
...
) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION "___";
```

Binary data in parquet files shouldn't separated by ASCII spaces unless you are referring to a single string-type column.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried doing it like the page sugests, but now the data is store in the datawarehouse file directory, but it is unable to show me a sample, as if it was empty. However when I do it with smaller parquet files it works. Could it be something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "data warehouse file directory". Creating an external table would point at an existing directory. If the table got associated with the wrong directory, then yes, the query would return no results. Or your schema doesn't match. IIRC, with Parquet, you don't need to specify column names and types as that information is already part of the files